# Bad numeric format

Tags: data-structures, pascal, record

So basically I have a record that looks like this

```
modulis = record
        kodas : string[4];
        pavadinimas : string[30];
        skaicius : integer;
        kiti : array[1..50] of string;
    end;
```

And I'm trying to read it from the text file like this :

```
ReadLn(f1,N);

for i := 1 to N do
    begin
        Read(f1,moduliai[i].kodas);
        Read(f1,moduliai[i].pavadinimas);
        Read(f1,moduliai[i].skaicius);
        for j := 1 to moduliai[i].skaicius do
            Read(f1,moduliai[i].kiti[j]);
        ReadLn(f1);
    end;
```

And the file looks like this :

```
9
IF01    Programavimo ivadas 0
IF02    Diskrecioji matematika  1 IF01
IF03    Duomenu strukturos  2 IF01 IF02
IF04    Skaitmenine logika  0
IF05    Matematine logika       1 IF04
IF06    Operaciju optimizavimas 1 IF05
IF07    Algoritmu analize       2 IF03 IF06
IF08    Asemblerio kalba        1 IF03
IF09    Operacines sistemos 2 IF07 IF08
```

And I'm getting 106 bad numeric format. Can't figure out how to fix this, I'm not sure, but I think it has something to do with the text file, however I copied the text file from the internet so it has to be good :|

Comment: 'kiti' is 'string' or 'string[5]'?

Comment: String but even if I change it to string[5], I get the same exact error. So now I found out that I get error at this lien Read(f1,moduliai[i].skaicius); if it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading string data is different from reading numeric data in Pascal.

With numbers the `Read` instruction consumes data until it hits white space or the end of file. Now white space in this case can be the space character, the tab character, the EOL 'character'. So if there are 2 numbers on one line of text, you could read them one by one using two consecutive `Read`s.

I believe you have already known that.

And I believe you thought it would work the same with strings. But it won't, you cannot read two string values from one line of text simply by using two consecutive `Read` instructions. `Read` would consume all the text up to EOL or EOF. After the reading the string variable is assigned however many characters it can hold, the rest of the data being thrown out into oblivion. It is essentially equivalent to `ReadLn` in this respect.

Solution? Arrange all the data in the input file on separate lines and better use `ReadLn`s instead of all the `Read`s. (But I think the latter might be unnecessary, and rearranging the input data might be enough.)

Alternatively you would need to read the whole line of text into a temporary string variable, then split it manually and assign the parts to the corresponding record fields, not forgetting also to convert the numeric values from `string` to `integer`.

You choose what suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have declared **pavadinimas** as string[30], it reads 30 character no matter what is the length of the string. For example in the following line pavadinimas will be 
**"    Skaitmenine logika  0"** instead of just **"Skaitmenine logika"**

```
IF04    Skaitmenine logika  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Pascal programmer, but it looks like the fields within your text file are not fixed length.  How would you expect your program to delimit each field during read back?